# How to Solve Web API timeout exception in .net Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i got an exception (like below image)  while executing the api ( in this api i am executing the Sql query ,and this query will take nearly 1hr 30 mins )  [image]

I have added **requestTimeout="02:30:00"**  in my web.config like below even though i got exception .

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="02:30:00" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Testexampleapi .dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

Is there any other property that i have added in .net Core ? .

Thanks

Victor Athoti.

Comment: I doubt that making API caller wait for a response from your API for 1hr 30 mins is good design in the first place.

Comment: @BohdanStupak, Actually that API throw that exception within 15 mins .

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. Why do you want your client to wait for 1.5hrs or more? This screams bad design. 2. What kind of ridiculously expensive SQL query are executing that takes over an hour to complete? This sounds like some form of data migration, which is a one and done job, no need to expose an API to do it

Comment: @MindSwipe : As i am trying to migrating the old Data base to new data base and it has almost 4 GB of data file , So it takes time to execute query ( it is depends on the data ) .

Comment: But then why expose an API to do it? Migrating data is a one and done type thing. You should and will never call that endpoint again, why expose it as an API?

Comment: @MindSwipe : Both data bases are different tables structures and i need to track how many records are  migrated and show that result on a screen ..  can you please guide me what is the best way to migrate the data using c# application..

Comment: You obviously have the C# code to migrate your database, but instead of putting it into an ASP.NET application, why not simply turn it into a console application and run as such?

Comment: Actually i am trying to Migrating the Database from Client local machine to Microsoft Azure DB , there is some firewall issues to connecting the Azure DB Database if i use Console .  I Use Selfhost project to collect data from my local data  and post to my API to import in to Azure DB .

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good pattern to use to keep an api call open for that time.
You should either use messaging or a callback, which the api can call when the process is complete.

Using a callback, the caller of the api can provide a callback url and it can be called by the api back to the caller.

Comment: Thank you for giving a thought , i will try it .